# write error message in txt file if error update each row of data in dbf file

Tags: vb.net, exception, logging

i have code here that i want to write error message in text file if each row of data is not update. can i know is it my try..catch block is right or wrong?

```
        For rCnt = 3 To 4
                Empno = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 1).Value
                totalhrs = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 3).Value 'workhr
                latehr = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 4).Value 'latehr
                earlyhr = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 5).Value 'earlyhr
                norOT = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 6).Value 'nor OT
                holOT = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 7).Value 'hol ot
                otherOT = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 8).Value 'other ot
                attend = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 9).Value 'attendace
                absent = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 10).Value 'absent
                mc = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 11).Value 'leave

                sCommand = "UPDATE paytran.dbf SET paytran.workhr = " & totalhrs & ", paytran.latehr = " & latehr & ", paytran.earlyhr = " & earlyhr & ", paytran.ot1 = " & norOT & ",  paytran.ot2 = " & holOT & ",  paytran.ot3 = " & otherOT & ", paytran.dw = " & attend & ", paytran.ab = " & absent & ", paytran.mc = " & mc & " , paytran.payyes = 'Y' WHERE paytran.empno == '" & Empno & "'"
                dBaseCommand = New OleDbCommand(sCommand, dBaseConnection)

                Try
                    retVal = dBaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Catch ex As IOException
                    'To_WriteAudit("Error", ex.Message.ToString()) 'here my catch block that write the file..
                End Try
            Next rCnt


Public Sub To_WriteAudit(ByVal pstrAction As String, ByVal pstrErrorDes As String)

    Dim pathlf As String

    pathlf = "C:\logfile.txt"

    Dim fswAuditLog As StreamWriter
    fswAuditLog = New StreamWriter(pathlf, True)
    fswAuditLog.WriteLine("Write the exception here")
    fswAuditLog.Flush()
    fswAuditLog.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried the code?

Comment: Prepare the `parameterized` SQL statement and I suggest to use `System.Diagnostics.TraceSource` or logging frameworks.

Comment: i have try the code..if have error,it not write in txt file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Try-Catch block is correct and should call to_writeaudit if there is an error in the update execution (when uncommented). However, you should also test retVal to make sure it is 1 (the number of rows updated). If it is zero, then nothing is updated. If it is more than zero, then more than one row was updated.

Also, you might want to put the assignments to sCommand and dBaseCommand inside the Try-Catch block in case they generate an error.

Comment: hi,i have try the catch...right now its worked to write the error message in text file...but,it not looping of each error message..
how can i do to make the each of error write in text file?

Comment: I would put a breakpoint in the Catch block and single-step from there to see what's happening.